# Wildcard route added but still for undefined route Cannot GET /

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6

I am using Angular 6 in my project. I Added wildcard route but still iam facing the error when i go to any undefined route angular gives `Cannot GET /<path>` in browser.

Below is my routes, all other defined routes are working perfectly fine but wildcard not working

```
const AppRoutes: Routes = [
 { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: "register", component: RegisterComponent },
 { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
 { path: "dashboard", component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
 { path:"backup",component:BackupComponent},
 { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
];
```

Routes are imported as default..

```
imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 ReactiveFormsModule,
 NgxPaginationModule,
 .
 .
 . 
 RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes),
],
```

For some reason i could not use hash based routing

```
//Can not use hash base routing in my case
RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, { useHash: true }),
```

I believe wildcard should work without hash based routing. Let me know where i am going wrong.

Comment: I am running the app with backend in NodeJS, running Angular and Node at same port through ng-build and node app.js
When i run angular with ng serve it works fine, but not with ng build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running the app with backend in NodeJS, running Angular and Node at same port through ng-build and node app.js When i run angular with ng serve it works fine, but not with ng build, but in production everythings seem good and wildcard working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no issue with your defined routes. However, [check this article](https://medium.com/@dao.houssene/angular-the-hash-trap-b2d415c2c241) for issue with your hash based routing.

Comment: I am running the app with backend in NodeJS, running Angular and Node at same port through ng-build and node app.js When i run angular with ng serve it works fine, but not with ng build

Answer (score 0):

This you can try to solve in 2 ways:

1. Try to change the order of parent route and wild card route such as

```
const AppRoutes: Routes = [
 { path: "register", component: RegisterComponent },
 { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
 { path: "dashboard", component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
 { path:"backup",component:BackupComponent},
 { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
];
```

2. Make use of `redirectTo` for `NotFoundComponent`.

Please check this article for more details [WildCardRoutes](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/wildcard-route-angular/#:%7E:text=A%20Wildcard%20route%20has%20a,redirect%20to%20an%20existing%20route)

Thanks